# Why is ひつよう considered a な adjective?

Tags: negation

Im struggling to understand why Hitsuyou (ひつよう) is considered a な adjective.

From what I understand after reading about い adjectives we simply drop the last い to make it negative, for example: さむい　becomes 住むくない because we dropped the last い and added くない to make cold become "not cold".

This is pretty simple to understand as each word we want to make negative usually has an い on the end.

However, using this same rule to use じゃない for な doesnt make sense to me with ひつよう as there is no な in the word.

Ive been reading through [this online dictionary](https://jlearn.net/Dictionary/Browse/1487660-hitsuyou-%E3%81%B2%E3%81%A4%E3%82%88%E3%81%86-%E5%BF%85%E8%A6%81) but still haven't been able to grasp why.

Can you help me understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the so-called "*-na* adjectives", the *-na* only appears when the adjective is used attributively -- when it used to modify a noun.  When these adjectives are used predicatively -- at the end of a sentence -- there is no *-na*.

Examples:

- この車【くるま】は静【しず】かです。 -- This car is quiet.
  これは静【しず】か**な**車【くるま】です。  -- This is a quiet car.
- この本【ほん】は必要【ひつよう】です。 -- This book is required / necessary.
  これは必要【ひつよう】**な**本【ほん】です。 -- This is a required / necessary book.

Note that じゃない negation can be used after both *-na* adjectives and nouns, and can be used both attributively (to modify a noun) and predicatively (at the end of a sentence).

- この車【くるま】は静【しず】か**じゃない**です。 -- This car is **not** quiet.
  これは静【しず】かな車【くるま】**じゃない**です。  -- This is **not** a quiet car. (It could be a loud car, or a slightly rattly car, or not even a car at all.)
  これは静【しず】か**じゃない**車です。 -- This is a **not-**​quiet car.  (A bit clunky in both the English and Japanese, but the meaning is clear.)

There's some more information over at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_equivalents_of_adjectives#na-adjective) that might be useful.

If you are still confused, please comment and I can expand this answer.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense. I was just worried that I wouldn't be able to know when an adjective is supposed to be a Na adjective. This helped a lot